# Parametrizing the solutions to a diophantine equation of degree four

Tags: diophantine-equations

Good evening,

Consider $x^4+y^4+z^4=2t^4$ where x,y,z,t integer.

Is it known how to find all parametrisation of this equation ?

If you have any parametrisation or reference of this equation, please post it

Thank you.

Comment: What is the context? Why are you interested in this particular equation and in a parametrization [of its solutions?] ?

Comment: Because I have an exercice , to solve my exercice I need parametrisation of this equation.

Comment: Might it be easier to start with $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 2t^{2}$?

Comment: However, Mathoverflow is not for asking for help with your homework problems...

Comment: Dear Arturo , I just ask if it is known parametrisation of the equation I posted. I don t ask solution of my homework. Don t patronize people.

Comment: Geoff , for z=t we get pythaorean triple x^2+y^2=t^2.

Comment: Geoff for z equal t , we get pythagorean triple in the equation you suggested.

Comment: I'm letting you know that math.overflow is not supposed to be for asking for help with homework (note that I did not say you were asking for a solution). I'm sorry if you think it's patronizing, it is not intended to be. There are other sites that are more welcoming to that kind of question (e.g., math.stackexchange). P.S. When replying to someone specifically, they will get a notification if you use the "at" sign, `@Geoff` for example, will produce a clickable link and a notification to the user addressed, if that user has posted comments or the answer you are replying to.

Comment: Well yes, but that does not parametrize the solutions of $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = 2t^{2}$.

Comment: Finally I found reference for parametrisation of x^4+y^4+z^4=t^4+u^4 zone

Comment: For those who are voting to close, I agree it's not great for the OP to say it's a homework problem; but it actually seems like a very hard problem, at least with the minor generalization of describing integers solutions for $x^4+y^4+z^4=at^4$ for different values of $a$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman who knows what OP actually need to do? They say "Because I have an exercice , to solve my exercice I need parametrisation of this equation." Why do they need this? What are they actually trying to achieve?  Maybe OP is actually on the wrong track to solving their HW. Furthermore, to me "hard" is not the only or even main criterion to decide suitability. (On the other hand the mere fact it is related to HW would not  bother me, if it were only clear what exactly is to be done.) I voted to close.

Answer (score 6):

Ramanujan gave two parametrizations: if $a+b+c=0$ then

$$a^4(b-c)^4+ b^4(c-a)^4+ c^4(a-b)^4= 2(ab+bc+ca)^4$$

and

$$(a^3+2abc)^4(b-c)^4+(b^3+2abc)^4(c-a)^4+(c^3+2abc)^4(a-b)^4=2(ab+ac+bc)^8$$

(listed in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html), equations 144 and 146). See also Bhargava, S. (1992) *On a family of Ramanujan's formulas for sums of fourth powers*. Ganita, 43 (1-2). pp. 63-67. [[abstract](http://eprints.uni-mysore.ac.in/10272/)] 
[[summary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BhargavasTheorem.html)]

The [F. Ferrari Identity (1909)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrarisIdentity.html) gives

$$(a^2+2ac-2bc-b^2)^4+ (b^2-2ba-2ca-c^2)^4+ (c^2+2cb+2ab-a^2)^4 = 2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab+bc+ca)^4$$

There is also [K. Ford's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FordsTheorem.html): if
$S_j=\sum_{i=j\,(\text{mod}\,3)}(-1)^i\binom ki a^{k-i}b^i$  then
$$(S_0-S_1)^4+(S_1-S_2)^4+(S_2-S_0)^4=2(a^2+ab+b^2)^{2k}$$

For $k=2$ and $k=4$, the Ford parametrizations are the same as the two Ramanujan ones. For $k=2$, this is simple, and for $k=4$, $S_0 = a^4-4 a b^3$, $S_1 = b^4-4 a^3 b$, $S_2 = 6 a^2 b^2$, and

$$\begin{align}
S_0 - S_1 = -(c^3+2abc)(a-b)\\
S_1 - S_2 = -(b^3+2abc)(c-a)\\
S_2 - S_0 = -(a^3+2abc)(b-c)\\
\end{align}$$

where $c=-a-b$.

**Edit:** A complete discussion of these identities, by S. Ramanujan, F. Ferrari and Kevin Ford, plus further identities by S. Bhargava, may be found on pages 96 to 101 of Bruce Berndt's *Ramanujan's Notebooks, Part IV* (1994), at e.g. http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan%27s%20Notebooks%20IV.pdf.

Comment: Correction: Link to Bruce Berndt's _Ramanujan's Notebooks, Part IV_, is now http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan's%20Notebooks%20IV.pdf.

Comment: Another update to the link: it now seems to need the Wayback Machine, https://web.archive.org/web/20150426023125/http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan's%20Notebooks%20IV.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "paramatrization"? Anyway, since your equation is homogeneous, you're really asking for $\mathbb Q$-rational points on the surface $S$ in $\mathbb P^3$ defined by your equation. The surface $S$ is an example of what is known as a K3 surface. Most likely what you have in mind for a paramatrization would be homogeneous polynomials $x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w),z(u,v,w),t(u,v,w)\in\mathbb Z[u,v,w]$ so that you get all solutions by plugging in integer values of $u$, $v$, and $w$. Such a solution very likely does not exist. Here's why. First, there is no way to parametrize the complex solutions using polynomial functions $x(u,v,w),y(u,v,w),z(u,v,w),t(u,v,w)\in\mathbb C[u,v,w]$, because a K3 surface is not birationally equivalent to $\mathbb P^2$. So that means there are two possibilities. First, the integer solutions are Zariski dense, in which case you won't have a parametrization. Second, the integer solutions lie on a finite number of curves. (I don't know offhand how to distinguish between these two possibilities.) However, is is conjectured that for any K3 surface, there is a finite extension $K/\mathbb Q$ such that the $K$-rational points are Zariski dense. So if it happens that you can parametrize the integer solutions to your particular equation, that's in some sense because your field $\mathbb Q$ isn't big enough to really reflect the arithmetic structure of the problem. And the solutions won't be that interesting, since they'd only be a finite number of one-parameter families.

Comment: Thank you Joe Silverman . I found  reference for parametric solutions Gerardin 1910, Ferrari 1913 intermédiaire des maths x^4+y^4+z^4=t^4+g^4

Comment: Thank you jeq for your reply , but that one does not help me for my exercice, the condition a+b+c=0 is not good for my exercice.Monday I will try to find Gerardin and Ferrari in library , it is closed the week-end in Paris.

Comment: @user81854 I don't understand. The three-fold $x^4+y^4+z^4=t^4+g^4$ is  in fact birational to $\mathbb P^3$, so it can be "parametrized" (although the parametrization is likely to be messy). But solutions to this equation will not give you solutions to your original equation $x^4+y^4+z^4=2t^4$ unless $t=g$, and I can pretty much guarantee that the parametrization of the 5-variable equation will not have $t=g$ in general. There's a big difference between a (smooth) quartic surface in $\mathbb P^3$ and a (smooth) quartic 3-fold in $\mathbb P^4$, both in their geometry and in their arithmetic.