# Solution of the Diophantine equation $x^4+y^4+z^4=2t^4$ are well-known?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Are solutions of the Diophantine equation $x^4+y^4+z^4=2t^4$ well-known?

I give a solution:

$x=m^2-n^2, y=m^2-2mn,  z=n^2-2mn, t=m^2+n^2-mn$

Comment: [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html) says "there are many solutions"

Comment: This is an example of  a K3 surface. You have found a copy of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Q}$ sitting inside the surface. A general conjecture says that there is some number field $K/\mathbb Q$ such that the $K$-rational points on the surface are Zariski dense. If you are interested in questions of this sort, you should read about K3 surfaces, both their geometry and their arithmetic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parametrizing the solutions to a diophantine equation of degree four](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221658/parametrizing-the-solutions-to-a-diophantine-equation-of-degree-four)